# Custom roles architecture in ASP.NET MVC 5, Dependency Injection issues

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity, ninject

I've got an architecture issue that I'm hoping someone can be of assistance to guide me in a more ideal strategy. The way I've been forced to do this reeks of "code smell".

I've got two different kinds of "Roles". I've got the built in Identity Roles, and I've got a custom set of roles (User Group Roles). I store these User Group Roles in a database, essentially a relationship between a user id, a usergroup role id, and a usergroup id. I'm using Ninject for dependency injection of my UserGroupService that handles all the CRUD operations of assigning users with certain usergroup roles to usergroups.

My first plan of attack was to create a custom authorization attribute that I could place on actions, similar to the Identity [Authorize(Role="")] attribute. I did not have any luck with this because I cannot inject a service into an attribute class (needs a parameterless constructor).

After that didn't work, my second plan of attack was to write an extension method for IPrincipal, essentially mimicking User.IsInRole("") with User.IsInUserGroupRole(""). This didn't work because I cannot inject a service into a static class.

Currently I am stuck including some booleans in the model of every view that has role based logic involved. So for instance:

```
public ActionResult Navigation()
    {
        var isSystemAdmin = User.IsInRole("Administrator");
        var isUserGroupAdmin = _userGroupService.IsUserGroupAdmin(User.Identity.GetUserId()) && !isSystemAdmin;
        var isGeneralUser = !isSystemAdmin && !isUserGroupAdmin;

        var model = new NavigationViewModel
        {
            IsSystemAdmin = isSystemAdmin,
            IsUserGroupAdmin = isUserGroupAdmin,
            IsGeneralUser = isGeneralUser
        };

        return PartialView("_Navigation", model);
    }
```

The issue here is that I have to do this  any time I want to determine what kind of roles the user is currently in. It works, but it smells.

Am I missing something here? I think the most ideal option would be the extension method strategy of being able to call it right off of User, but cannot seem to make that work.

Answer (score 0):

Constructor DI is not the only way to get access to a dependency.

Each IOC has a way of resolving a dependency, all you need is a reference to the IOC container. So, even if your attribute requires a parameterless constructor you could still resolve the dependency manually.

Something like this should help :

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/47fc0a/resolving-dependency-using-ninject/

Is it a great way to use your IOC this way? Probably not but it sure beats what you're doing now.